# How to use React-router with {this.props.children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new with react and I am trying to use props in my test page. Once I used {this.props.children}, all the content is still being replaced instead of been showed at the children declaration.

How can I do to use the props.children to display the page?

**src/app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { IndexRoute, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './pages/App';
import Cursos from './pages/Cursos';
import Sobre from './pages/Sobre';
import Home from './pages/Home';


ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history = { hashHistory } >
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/cursos" component={ Cursos } />
      <Route path="/sobre" component={ Sobre } />
      <Route component={ Home } />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  ),
      document.getElementById("app")
  );
```

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>V++ React Series</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="app"></div>
    <script src="/js/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/Pages/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="nav has-shadow">
                    <div className="nav-left">
                        <NavLink to="/home" className="nav-item is-tab">Home  </NavLink>
                        <NavLink to="/cursos" className="nav-item is-tab" activeClassName="is-active">Cursos  </NavLink>
                        <NavLink to="/sobre" className="nav-item  is-tab" activeClassName="is-active">Sobre  </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <section className="section">
                    <div className="container">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**src/Pages/Cursos.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Cursos extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return <h1 className="title">Conheça nossos cursos</h1>
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this.props.children in your case?

Comment: it was expected to show the page "Cursos" under the NavLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can determine it looks like you want your Navbar to be displayed on all of your pages and the `<Cursos />` component should be displayed in the container inside `<App />` to do this using `{this.props.children}` you can change your router to look like this:

```
  <Router history = { hashHistory } >
    <Switch>
      <App>
        <Route path="/cursos" component={ Cursos } />
        <Route path="/sobre" component={ Sobre } />
        <Route component={ Home } />
      </App>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Bear in mind that this will also display `<Sobre />` and `<Home />` in the same fashion.

Comment: Hey, I am having trouble with props.children. Your answer has helped me get a little closer to making my app work. Only now it is telling me 'props' is not defined. Do you have any clue what this may be?